# Is there any way to get back to a page from which it was redirected to in django?

Tags: python, django, django-views

***Detailed Explanation:***

Suppose there is an html page in django named as **Page 1** and the other one as **Page 2** which is a login page. Now there is a button on both of these pages. The button on **Page 1** redirects to the page for login. Is there any way to get back to the previous page **Page 1** from where the **Page 2** is redirected from?

Please Note: The login page i.e. the **Page 2** is simply redirected to a Account.html page, I want that it will redirect back to previous page, i.e., from where the **Page 2** was redirected from.

Comment: you can use `url` tag of django for this by giving `name` your last `argument` in `path()`, for more help from community, edit your question with actual code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: It would be helpful to know what action should cause the redirect back to the previous page.

Comment: @MiloPersic the method is post... on the login url itself.